# Use properties in Mongobee ChangeSet

Tags: jhipster

I would like to use a property in a MongoBee ChangeSet.
I have a list of emails for which I would like to create ADMIN accounts.

```
application:
    roles:
        admins: some@email.com
```

I have tried multiple solutions, like:

- Using @Value

```java
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class InitialSetupMigration {
    @Value("${application.roles.admins}")
    String admins;
```

- Creating a ConfigurationProperties

```java
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="application.roles")
public class InitialSetupMigration {
    String admins;
```

But none of them work

Answer (score 1):

You can use **environment** variable to get properties.

For this purpose you need:

1. inject org.springframework.core.env.Environment to your runner in Mongo Configuration class

```java
    @Bean @Autowired
    public Mongobee mongobee(Environment environment) {
      Mongobee runner = new Mongobee(uri);
      runner.setSpringEnvironment(environment)
      //... etc
    }
```

2. Use **Environment environment** as a parameter of changeSet method

```java
    @ChangeSet(order = "006", id = "someChangeWithSpringDataTemplate",
    author = "testAuthor") public void someChange5(MongoTemplate
    mongoTemplate, Environment environment) {

    }
```

3. Get needed properties:

```java
    environment.getProperty("application.roles.admins")
```

It can help [mongobee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee).